# Image not uploaded - Django Server

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, django-uploads

I'm trying to send an image android(client) to django(server) by converting it into base64 string. I've received the string @ the server side, decoded and renamed it.However, when I try to save the image it fails.

Here's the path where the image is supposed to be stored on the server.
models.py

```
class App(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #create_date = models.DateTimeField('date created')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    app_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to="/root/AR_BROWSER/example/static/uploaded_pics", null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(App_User)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The function in views.py

```
@csrf_exempt    
def create_app(request):
    appName = request.POST['name']
    user = request.POST['userID']
    c = request.POST['category']
    i = request.POST['image']
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(i)
    t = datetime.now()
    filename = t.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S.jpg') 
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(imgdata)
    u=App_User.objects.get(id=user)
    apps = App.objects.create(name = appName, category=c, user_id = u.id, app_logo=filename)
    apps.save()

    return HttpResponse("You created %s." % apps.name)
```

Comment: replace `app_logo=filename` with `app_logo=f`

Comment: doesn't work.The value is stored in filename not f

Comment: @MatthewHarrison yeah but I don't remember what was the solution.